# gradient of nonlinear function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system, neural-networks

[image]

Why is the yellow equality holds ? According to which formulas, meaning, observations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that
$$a\in \mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow dX^Ta \in \mathbb{R}^m \Rightarrow \Phi' dX^Ta \in \mathbb{R}^m \Rightarrow c^T\Phi' dX^Ta \in \mathbb{R} $$
and the trace of a constant is the constant.

To see that $\Phi' : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ just notice that $\varphi$ takes points of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and can be multiplied at the left by $c^T$.

Comment: by the way $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\cdot m}$ and not as written, it's a typo as much as I can notice, right ? because $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ? so $X^Ta\:$ could be defined.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or $m=n$.